# PHP nested array remove specific keys by condition

Tags: php

I am using `PHP 5.5.2` with `MySQL` back-end. I have a `self-referencing database table` from that I am getting an `array` as below :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 47
            [s_id] => 
            [m_id] => 
            [title] => Aaa
            [type] => G
            [created_at] => 2014-08-29 06:05:18
            [frequency] => d
            [start] => 2014-08-29
            [time] => 09:00
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 48
                            [s_id] => 37
                            [m_id] => 
                            [title] => bbbbbbbbbbbbb
                            [type] => Q
                            [created_at] => 2014-08-29 06:05:18
                            [frequency] => 
                            [start] => 
                            [time] => 
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 49
                                            [s_id] => 38
                                            [m_id] => 
                                            [title] => cccccccccc
                                            [type] => A
                                            [created_at] => 2014-08-29 06:05:18
                                            [frequency] => 
                                            [start] => 
                                            [time] => 
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 50
                                            [s_id] => 39
                                            [m_id] => 
                                            [title] => ddddddddd dddd 
                                            [type] => A
                                            [created_at] => 2014-08-29 06:05:18
                                            [frequency] => 
                                            [start] => 
                                            [time] => 
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 51
                                            [s_id] => 40
                                            [m_id] => 
                                            [title] => eeeeeee eeeeeee.
                                            [type] => A
                                            [created_at] => 2014-08-29 06:05:18
                                            [frequency] => 
                                            [start] => 
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 54
                            [s_id] => 18
                            [m_id] => 
                            [title] => fffffffff ffff
                            [type] => Q
                            [created_at] => 2014-08-29 06:05:18
                            [frequency] => 
                            [start] => 
                            [time] => 
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 55
                                            [s_id] => 19
                                            [m_id] => 
                                            [title] => gggggg gggggg
                                            [type] => A
                                            [created_at] => 2014-08-29 06:05:18
                                            [frequency] => 
                                            [start] => 
                                            [time] => 
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 56
                                            [s_id] => 20
                                            [m_id] => 
                                            [title] => hhhhhhhhhh hhhh
                                            [type] => A
                                            [created_at] => 2014-08-29 06:05:18
                                            [frequency] => 
                                            [start] => 
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 57
                            [s_id] => 21
                            [m_id] => 
                            [title] => iiiiiiii iiii
                            [type] => Q
                            [created_at] => 2014-08-29 06:05:18
                            [frequency] => 
                            [start] => 
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 58
                                            [s_id] => 22
                                            [m_id] => 
                                            [title] => jjjjjjj jjj
                                            [type] => A
                                            [created_at] => 2014-08-29 06:05:18
                                            [frequency] => 
                                            [start] => 
                                            [time] => 
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 59
                                            [s_id] => 23
                                            [m_id] => 
                                            [title] => kkkkkkkk kkkk
                                            [type] => A
                                            [created_at] => 2014-08-29 06:05:18
                                            [frequency] => 
                                            [start] => 
                                            [time] => 
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
        [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 47
            [s_id] => 
            [m_id] => 
            [title] => xxxx xxx xxx 
            [type] => G
            [created_at] => 2014-08-29 06:05:18
            [frequency] => d
            [start] => 2014-08-29
            [time] => 09:00
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 112
                            [s_id] => 37
                            [m_id] => 
                            [title] => lllllllllll llllll
                            [type] => Q
                            [created_at] => 2014-08-29 06:05:18
                            [frequency] => 
                            [start] => 
                            [time] => 
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 113
                                            [s_id] => 38
                                            [m_id] => 
                                            [title] => mmmmmmm mmmm
                                            [type] => A
                                            [created_at] => 2014-08-29 06:05:18
                                            [frequency] => 
                                            [start] => 
                                            [time] => 
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 123
                                            [s_id] => 39
                                            [m_id] => 
                                            [title] => nnnnnnnnn hhhhh
                                            [type] => A
                                            [created_at] => 2014-08-29 06:05:18
                                            [frequency] => 
                                            [start] => 
                                            [time] => 
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 456
                            [s_id] => 18
                            [m_id] => 
                            [title] => ppppppp pppppp
                            [type] => Q
                            [created_at] => 2014-08-29 06:05:18
                            [frequency] => 
                            [start] => 
                            [time] => 
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 545
                                            [s_id] => 19
                                            [m_id] => 
                                            [title] => qqqqqqqqq qqq
                                            [type] => A
                                            [created_at] => 2014-08-29 06:05:18
                                            [frequency] => 
                                            [start] => 
                                            [time] => 
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 435
                                            [s_id] => 20
                                            [m_id] => 
                                            [title] => ssssssssss sssssssssss 
                                            [type] => A
                                            [created_at] => 2014-08-29 06:05:18
                                            [frequency] => 
                                            [start] => 
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

There might be `N nesting levels` in this `array`.

Now for each array element, if `['type']` is `G` then I want to `remove keys [s_id]` and `[m_id]` and for `any other type` I want to `remove keys [start], [end]` and `[time]`.

**Edit : I have tried using a recursive function but it is not giving the desired result.**

```
private function getarray(array &$arr){

    foreach ($arr as $item)
    {
        switch ($item['type'])
        {
            case 'G' : 
                unset($item['s_id'],  $item['m_id']);
            break; 
            default : 
                unset($item['start'],  $item['end'], $item['time']);
            break;
        }

        foreach ($item["children"] as $c)
        {
            $child = array();
            getarray($child);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Whoever you are, before down-voting this question, dare to specify an answer or any link that gives this specific answer.

Comment: Write some recursive function

Comment: @u_mulder So you are the down voter right? Give me any example for this if you have. I have posted this answer after trying a lot to achieve this.

Comment: I'm not a downvoter, but could be, as you provided no efforts in fulfilling task (printing array is not a real effort)

Comment: Let me edit the question, by placing what I have tried.

Comment: Now if anyone have any answer then please post it.

Comment: Seems like working with jealous php guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it myself :

```
private function getarray(array &$arr){

        foreach ($arr as &$item)
        {
            switch ($item['type'])
            {
                case 'G' : 
                    unset($item['s_id'], $item['m_id']);
                    break; 

                default : 
                    unset($item['start'], $item['end'], $item['time']);
                    break;
            }
            if (is_array($item['children']) && sizeof($item['children']) > 0){
                getarray($item['children']);
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is working fine. I have posted this answer to help other people who are novice to php and trying to overcome their problem.

And this is a slap to the jealous people who did not helped me but asked "What did you tried so long?" with a superiority complex attitude. I did it myself.

Comment: You have to try and save your problem on your own before you ask a question on SO.
That's why people asked you what you tried before posting here.

Comment: Look at my reputation on SO. I always try to resolve my problems enough before posting it over here. But the thing is why are you down voting someone's question in just 10 seconds it has posted? If you haven't done any effort to help them to resolve it, you don't have any right to act like that.

Comment: Also look at the answer you have posted. It was not resolving the question I have asked but still I haven't down-voted it because it might be helpful to someone else. Once it is down voted, others will give up trying it indeed it is the solution they are searching for. The thing is attitude that makes you different.

Comment: I didn't downvote anything here. I just pointed out the possible reason why people asked you to show what you have already tried. Downvotes will happen once in a while, don't be offended by that.

Answer (score 1):

```
function filterMyArray($arr){
 if(isset($arr['type'] && $arr['type'] == 'G'){
   unset($arr['s_id']);
   unset($arr['m_id']);
 }
else if(isset($arr['type']){
  unset($arr['start']);
  unset($arr['end']);
  unset($arr['time']);
}
if(isset($arr['children'])
  $arr['children'] = filterMyArray($arr['children']);
return $arr;
}
```

This function is not tested, I wrote it from memory.
But seriously, Googling something like that doesn't hurt. It would take you 5 minutes to get all the required knowledge to do this...

Comment: `filterMcArray` in a recursive call, not `filterArray`